# Why is my HUD not rendering in OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl, rendering, hud

I'm new to OpenGL, and I've been going through NeHe's tutorials and various other web sources, and I'm testing some things to render text as a HUD of sorts over everything else.
After a very long night, I can't get this to work and I can't find any solutions here that work, so I thought I'd ask.

My code:

```
GLvoid glLoadHUD(GLvoid)
{
    glPushAttrib(GL_LIGHTING_BIT |
                    GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT |
                    GL_TEXTURE_BIT);

    glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glPushMatrix();
            glLoadIdentity();
            glOrtho(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
            glRasterPos2f(0.1f, 0.6f);
            glColor3f(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f);
            glPrint("Test.");
            glRasterPos2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
        glPopMatrix();
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glPopAttrib();

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);  
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
}
```

Which is the code to render the text, and this is the code for drawing the scene:

```
int DrawGLScene(GLvoid)                                         
{

glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); // Clears buffers
glLoadIdentity();

// If I put glLoadHUD(); here, it renders but the models render over it,
    //  which is useless.

for (xloop = 0; xloop < 3;)
{
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(-4.0f+(float(xloop)*4.0f),0.0f,-12.0f);
    glCallList(dlstBox);    // This is the call to create a box.
    xloop++;
}


glLoadHUD();  // If I put it here though, it doesn't render at all.

return TRUE;
}
```

Thank you in advance for any help you could give, I know I'm pretty green and I'm sure it's staring me right in the face, but this is driving me mad and I'm not sure how to make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `glLoadHud` after the rest of the scene, your `MODELVIEW` matrix is still on the stack, and you do not clear it as part of `glLoadHud`. Thus all of the `glTranslatef` translations that you accumulate during the scene are still active when you're drawing the hud, which translates it right out of your viewable window.

Clear the `MODELVIEW` matrix as part of the start of `glLoadHud` and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: That was it!
Thank you very much. Now I can finally move past that without tearing any hair out.

Answer (score 0):

It might be printing inside your z-clipping so it will not show up on your screen. So, move out of the screen a little bit and see if it shows up.

Comment: tried that, but that wasn't it. i think that would've affected it when i rendered the HUD before hand too, which is where that didn't work sadly.
but thank you! definitely something worth keeping in mind, i'm sure that'll trip me up sooner or later.

Comment: On second thought, you were actually on the something there, the initial translation was affecting it so it was rendering 12.0f into the screen as well.